# Need explanation on Project Tree Android Studio

Tags: android, project

I may be missing something here but, how come my android project tree used to look like that when I created my first project 5 months ago (with folders like .idea, build, or R.java)

[image]

And now, I've just created a new projet and it looks like that :

[image]

Did I make a mistake at some point ? How can I display all the folders and files like R.java ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the files outside of Android Studio, you should find that the structure is nearly identical.

What you are seeing is the new Android project view. Note that at the very top of your screenshots the first one says "project" and the second one says "Android."

The Android project view simplifies the way the information is present a bit- for example, it will put all your Gradle scripts together and it will combine drawables with the same name to make finding different versions of the same drawable a bit easier.

If you don't like the new view, you can click on "Android" to see a dropdown containing other options, including the old Project view.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, silly mistake : the view was different.

[image]